# Can't load static contents(css,js,img...) When Application Request Routing(ARR) with Azure Web Apps

Tags: azure, iis, arr

I have two mvc based web sites with azure web apps(site01.azurewebsites.net,site02,azurewebsites.net forexample) .

Now I'm struggling to set ARR from site01(original) to site02(destination).
Loading cshtml file is fine(site02's cshtml shows) but static contents aren't read correctly.

When rewrited to site02 from site01, cshtml tried to read css-images in site01's servers path because ARR just makes routing and browser url doesn't change.

In short, html is read site02(destination) and other static contents are read site01(original).

How can i do it??
If you have any suggestions, please reply.

Thanks for reading!!